# Dynamic link / Dynamic typing in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have seen in the BNR 3rd edition an example to do a static singleton class.
To do that, they explain how to avoid a creation cycle calling the superclass alloc:

```
static MyClass *myclass = [[super alloc] init];
```

MyClass has its own init method.

```
NSObject -> MyClass
```

My doubt is: Which init class is sent? NSOject init, or MyClass init

Nested alloc init equals:

`myclass = [super alloc]` and then
`myclass = [myclass init]` ???????????

OR

`myclass = [super alloc]` and then `myclass = [super init]`

Comment: where did your find this code? it doesn't look right. is this code been placed in `alloc` method?

Comment: Big nerd Ranch 3rd edition. it is inside the method: + (Myclass *) sharedStore

Comment: I'll try to trace in nslog messages to myclass in the alloc init sequence

Comment: did you override `alloc` method? otherwise I cannot see any reason of using `super`

Comment: Yes, it's overriden the allocwithzone. it sends then sharedStore message again, and that is the reason of using super.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `super`, but do use `self`. Otherwise subclassing of your singleton will not work. The correct way is something like this:

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance {
  static MyClass *instance = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    instance = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return instance;
}
```

`dispatch_once` guarantees that your code (block in this case) is called only once. And `self` guarantees that subclassing will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

for you question, the selector is always called on the subclass's implementation, which is your first guess

the way described in the book is a valid way to implement singleton, but i do not suggest it though. Robert Vojta's solution is good.

i cannot see how necessary to override `allocWithZone`, then you also need to make sure `init`  does nothing (at least not leak)

Comment: Thanks, i need to clarify the subclass calling

Answer (score 0):

Just for add some tests:

I have created 2 MyClass classes: NSObject -> Myclass -> My2ndClass

So:

```
@implementation Myclass
    +(id) sharedClass {
    static Myclass *miclase = nil;
    miclase = [[self alloc] init];    
    NSLog(@"%@", [super description]);
    return miclase;
}

-(id)init {    
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"init de Myclass");
    return self;
}
-(NSString *)description {
    return @"i am Myclass";
}
@end
```

AND:

```
@implementation My2ndClass
+(id) sharedClass {
    static My2ndClass *miclase = nil;
    miclase = [[super alloc] init];
    //miclase = [super init];  CRASH
    NSLog(@"%@", [super description]);
    return miclase;
}

-(id)init {    
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"init de My2ndClass");
    NSLog(@"%@", [super description]);
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)description {
    return @"i am My2ndClass";
}
@end
```

Then in AppDelegate:

```
Myclass *miclase = [Myclass sharedClass];
My2ndClass *mi2ndclase = [My2ndClass sharedClass];
```

This is the console output:

```
2012-09-03 17:18:55.742 Dynamic Typing[2891:207] init de Myclass
2012-09-03 17:18:55.744 Dynamic Typing[2891:207] Myclass
2012-09-03 17:18:55.746 Dynamic Typing[2891:207] init de Myclass
2012-09-03 17:18:55.747 Dynamic Typing[2891:207] init de My2ndClass
2012-09-03 17:18:55.748 Dynamic Typing[2891:207] i am Myclass
2012-09-03 17:18:55.751 Dynamic Typing[2891:207] My2ndClass
```

Like xlc0212 told, the correct messages when they are nested are:

```
miclase = [super alloc];
miclase = [miclase init];
```

Besides, if i do

```
miclase = [super alloc]
```

and then

```
miclase = [super init]
```

it CRASHES.

When is sent a class method (+) [super description], it logs class name (Myclass and My2ndClass). They are de class itself and don't have super object, do they?

Comment: in you test, the `super` in class method represent the class object of the super class, which does not have `+(id)init` method implemented, so it crashed